# Can I create a Oculus Rift app using the Spotify API?

Tags: spotify, oculus

I have a question I want to know before development.
Can I create Oculus Rift apps using the Spotify API?
If I create an app using the Spotify API, can't I pay and sell it?

I would appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0):

> Unless you receive Spotify’s written approval, and except as otherwise set out in this Section IV, 2., commercial uses are not permitted for SDAs (Spotify Developer Application

Check out Section 4, Part 2 for more information on [their terms of service](https://developer.spotify.com/terms/#vi)

Basically, you have to be approved by Spotify to sell it. If you search the [Github web-api issues](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20commercial%20), you will find others requesting for commercial access where turnaround could take months.